# Making BeautifulSoup ignore contents inside script tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have been trying to get BeautifulSoup (3.1.0.1)to parse a html page that has a lot of javascript that generates html inside  tags. 
One example fragment looks like this :

```
<html><head><body><div>
<script type='text/javascript'>

if(ii > 0) {
html += '<span id="hoverMenuPosSepId" class="hoverMenuPosSep">|</span>'
}
html += 
'<div class="hoverMenuPos" id="hoverMenuPosId" onMouseOver=\"menuOver_3821();\" ' +
'onMouseOut=\"menuOut_3821();\">';
if (children[ii].uri == location.pathname) {
html += '<a class="hiHover" href="' +  children[ii].uri + '" ' + onClick + '>';
} else {
html += '<a class="hover" href="' +  children[ii].uri + '" ' + onClick + '>';
}
html += children[ii].name + '</a></div>';
}
}          
hp = document.getElementById("hoverpopup_3821");
hp.style.top = (parseInt(hoveritem.offsetTop) + parseInt(hoveritem.offsetHeight)) + "px";
hp.style.visibility = "Visible";
hp.innerHTML = html;
}
return false;
}
function menuOut_3821() {
timeOn_3821 =  setTimeout("showSelected_3821()",  1000)             
}
var timeOn_3821 = null;
function menuOver_3821() {
clearTimeout(timeOn_3821)
}   
function showSelected_3821() {
showChildrenMenu_3821( 
document.getElementById("flatMenuItemAnchor" + selectedPageId), selectedPageId);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

BeautifulSoup doesn't seem to be able to deal with this and is complaning about "malformed start tag" around the onMouseOver=**\"**menuOver_3821();\". 
It seems to try parsing the xml that is generated by javascript inside the script block ?!?

Any ideas how to make BeautifulSoup ignores the script tags content ?

I have seen other suggestion of using lxml but can't since it has to run on Google AppEngine.

Comment: Perhaps you are experiencing this bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=516824

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Reverting to BeautifulSoup 3.0.7a solved the problem and it was able to deal with other dodgy html bits that 3.1.0.1 choked on.

Answer (score 1):

Reverting to BeautifulSoup [3.0.7a](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/3.x/BeautifulSoup-3.0.7a.tar.gz) solved this issue and many other html oddities that 3.1.0.1 has choked on.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this kind of problem before, and what I normally do is replace every occurrence of `<script` with `<!--` and `</script>` with `-->`. That way, all the `<script></script>` tags are commented out.

Comment: Good point but would not work if script tag itself contains <!-- -->

Comment: That is quite true. I suppose you could implement a sanity check such that when a <script is encountered, it sets a flag that removes --> until a </script> tag is encountered, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

That would work, but the point of BeautifulSoup is parsing whatever tag soup you throw at it, even if it's horribly ill-formed.

Comment: What about the times when BeautifulSoup chokes on `<` and `>` in `<script>` tags with loading the html, though? For me, this crash happens when loading the html `BeautifulSoup(badHtml)`.

Comment: Then that would be a bug in BeautifulSoup.